# Why do I get "Access Denied" on every page?

Tags: 8

I've been trying out Drupal 8 on localhost which has been great, and I've now transferred it to a server, but every page gives me *Access Denied*. I can't even access the front page, or the user login page.

I have tried truncating the session and cache tables, and deleting cookies, but don't know what else to try. I've also installed drush, cleared the cache, and tried user-login drush command - still no access.

What things should I check? How do I fix this?

Comment: Got the same situation over here.  Same code and db locally work fine, but on platform.sh access denied everywhere.  Strange.  Since this is a top search result, I hope I remember to come back here once I've figured it out. :)

Answer (score 17):

Don't edit core code as suggested by Flounders answer. If you're not using HTTP auth then simply disable the Basic Auth module via the UI or Drush:

```
drush pmu basic_auth -y
```

Drupal has different authentication providers. The defaults are: basic_auth and cookie, basic_auth has a higher priority but is not enabled by default.

Comment: I had similar problem But uninstalling is not the solution. So how do we perform basic authentication?

Comment: Please don't edit this answer unless you're actually adding value to it, if you have comments to add, leave a comment.

Comment: uninstall won't solve the problem. we need a basic auth on our Site.

Answer (score 4):

If you came here with the intention on figuring out why your **Drupal 8** site is now throwing ***Access Denied*** messages after enabling the **[Relaxed](https://www.drupal.org/project/relaxed)** module (dependency on **[Workspace](https://www.drupal.org/project/workspace)** which is also dependent on core's [Basic_Auth](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/basic_auth/) module) you'll want to read this:

https://www.drupal.org/node/2842858

It took me several days of hunting around to finally get the right Google Search query to find the right answer. I hope this finds others in the same spot I was in.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen to me when I accidentally changed the password of the mysql username that Drupal was using for authentication to the DB.  Make sure the DB user/pass is correct in settings.php.

Answer (score -4):

After debugging I found what was the problem for me.

Drupal has some authentication providers. For standard pages this are:
basic_auth and cookie (basic_auth has higher priority).

Because test site has a basic_auth from the htaccess, this resulted in that Drupal marked my request as using basic_auth.
Only all pages did not require this. 
Result was just redirect to the 403 page (access denied in the watchdog table)

My temporary fix was the following:
Open the file core/modules/basic_auth/src/Authentication/Provider/BasicAuth.php

Go to this code:

```
public function applies(Request $request) {
    $username = $request->headers->get('PHP_AUTH_USER');
    $password = $request->headers->get('PHP_AUTH_PW');
    return isset($username) && isset($password);
}
```

Change it to this:

```
public function applies(Request $request) {
    return false;
    //$username = $request->headers->get('PHP_AUTH_USER');
    //$password = $request->headers->get('PHP_AUTH_PW');
    //return isset($username) && isset($password);
}
```

If there is a better solution, let me know. But this makes the site working.

Comment: You shouldn't edit core code, see my answer for an alternative solution.

Comment: @benjy Your answer is not a solution.

Comment: Don't ever hack core code. There are better troubleshooting techniques out there.